# how to Triger useEffect in unit test jest & enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

this is my code

```js
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchAccount} from './store/actions/accountProp'
export default function StackList() {
  const actionId = 123;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAccount(actionId));
  }, [])

  const {account,accountDetails} = useSelector((state)=>state.accountData)
  return (
    <div>
      {account}-{accountDetails}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am unable to find any appropriate document to test useEffect in jest.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I would not recommend using enzyme for testing React applications any more, especially if they are using Hooks.

I would recommend the lecture of this article as background info: https://www.piotrstaniow.pl/goodbye-enzyme

Instead, I would recommend you look into [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) which is what most of the community nowadays uses - and which works very well with hooks.